# colab getting crashed while running the python script

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, google-colaboratory, bioinformatics

i'm using the following code for merging two excel files which has around 800k rows in each, is there any other way to merge the files in same fashion or any solution?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("master file.csv")
df1=pd.read_csv("onto_diseas.csv")
df4=pd.merge(df, df1, left_on = 'extId', right_on = 'extId', how = 'inner')
df4
```

Comment: You could load just one of the files, only its "extId" column. Then, read the second (bigger) file in chunks, only its "extId" column, while checking if there's a match in with your first dataframe. At the end you'll have all the "extId" that exist in both CSVs and work with that subset of data. (Since your colab crashed doing this, it might be because it ran out of memory)

Comment: @aaossa i don't know but not showing any ram related information but in log i'm getting following "tcmalloc: large alloc 9193373696 bytes == 0x5642ddfb0000".

Answer (score 0):

Try use dask or drill for merging or specify datatypes demanding less memory while (float16 instead float64 & so forth) creating dataframes. I could show this in code if you provide links to your files.

Comment: it'll be helpful if you can provide the code, those are large files, not sure they are that much helpful.

Comment: @Arvind I have asked for data in order that I can try my guesses myself and post a verified solution.